# Page_PreRender and Global.asax

Tags: asp.net

I want to bind to the Page PreRender method on at the global.asax level, but for some reason the method is never getting called. My method looks like:

```
    protected void Page_PreRender(object source, EventArgs e)
    {
        /* do stuff */
    }
```

Am I able to call Page events like this in Global.asax?

Comment: why you want call pre render from global asax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The global.asax is derived from HttpApplication class and not contain the Page_PreRender event as you can see on the MSDN reference:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication(VS.90).aspx

If you want to globally capture the PreRender event you can make a different base class for the `System.Web.UI.Page`, overwrite this event, and use this class to your pages.

For example

```
public abstract class BasePage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreRender(e);
    }
}
```

and use the `BasePage` on your pages